# Applying mask image for erasing with Win2D

Tags: win2d

I want to make transparent (erase) particular area of an image using Win2D.

For that purpose I have a mask which contains transparent colour 
(RRGGBBAA = xxxxxx00) for pixels that need to be erased, and white colour (RRGGBBAA = FFFFFFFF) for pixels that should stay.

Ideally, I need either *CanvasBlend.And* or *CanvasBlend.Mutiply*, but neither of those is provided with Win2D. However, there is *CanvasBlend.Min*, which, as I expect, should also do the job.

Here is the code:

```
  internal static CanvasBitmap applyMask(
        ICanvasResourceCreatorWithDpi creator,
        CanvasBitmap sourceBmp, CanvasBitmap maskBmp,
        CanvasBlend blendMode = CanvasBlend.Min) {

        var destSize = sourceBmp.Size;
        var crt = new CanvasRenderTarget(creator, destSize);
        var rect = new Rect(new Point(), destSize);

        using (var ds = crt.CreateDrawingSession()) {
             ds.Blend = CanvasBlend.SourceOver;
             ds.DrawImage(sourceBmp, rect);
             ds.Blend = blendMode;
             ds.DrawImage(maskBmp, rect);
        }

        return crt;
  }
```

It comes up with showing source image completely unmodified, as if masked image opacity (Alpha) is ignored. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the recently added AlphaMaskEffect: https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Effects_AlphaMaskEffect.htm

Comment: Yes, alpha mask effect is what is really needed, but it works only with Windows 10 Aniversary, while my app supports Windows 8.1+. At the moment I do it  manually through WriteableBitmap.  I mark it as an asnwer given that nothing else is available.